# WSO2 API Manager. Authorization code grant PKCE

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I use WSO2 API Manager 2.5.0 and authorization code grant for getting access token. But now I need to authenticate my mobile client. I can't keep client secret at mobile client. And I found that authorization code grant support Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE) without necessity to send client secret on the second step of the flow (https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/pkce/). But I not found any setting in WSO2 API Manager Store connected with PKCE.

Is authorization code grant using PKCE supported in WSO2 API Manager?

Comment: I don't think you can set pkce in the store. You may tty to use wso2is-km (identity server as a key manager) and there you can configure additional application settings. Regardless that  imho the pkce is not a solution. it merely only mitigates code intercept attack.. For mobile app without own backend services you may use implicit token grant